# Does value-of select always return string?

Tags: xslt

I have a HTML code to be replaced by

```
<xsl:value-of select="proj/test/output"/>
```

e.g. with

```
<font color='green'>Hello world!</font>
```

But when I use this, I could not succeed in letting browser interpret this as a HTML code.

Normally it should simply write green Hello world! but instead, it writes exactly the same without interpreting anything.

Is there any way to let browser interpret this as it is but not write as it is a text?

The comment below the question solved the problem. Only thing I needed to add was `using disable-output-escaping="yes"`

So:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="proj/test/output"/>
```

Works...

Comment: Do you mean the HTML elements are there _as XML_ within the `output` element or is the HTML escaped as text (i.e. `<output>&lt;font ...</output>` or `<output><![CDATA[<font ... ]]></output>`)?  If the former, use `<xsl:copy-of select="proj/test/output/node()"/>`, if the latter then you'll have to see whether your processor supports `disable-output-escaping`

Comment: @IanRoberts what I want is to see green text instead of any code. so probably the latter one, but I do not know how to modify this settings. I may try to find it, but it seems very hard.

Comment: @IanRoberts OK great! it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy the whole node, use on example `copy-of`:

```
<copy-of select="proj/test/output"/>
```

Difference:

- `value-of` - copies only text from the selected node.
- `copy-of` - copies all elements from the selected node (elements can be another tags or text).

From the [XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of):

> The xsl:value-of element is instantiated to create a text node in the result tree.
>
> (...)
>
> The xsl:copy-of element can be used to copy a node-set over to the result tree without converting it to a string.

Comment: Unfortunately this gave the following result which is I did not want. `<output>&lt;font color='green'&gt;Hello world!&lt;/font&gt;</output>`

Comment: What output did you exaclty expect?

Comment: Only the green text disabling stripping html tags. The the Ian's answer below my answer as comment solved my problem